# Ionic2 Detect Scroll to Bottom event

Tags: angular, scroll, ionic2

This is causing me a lot of headache recently.
All I want to do is detect when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page.

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Groceries</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content >

    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let grocery of groceries">{{grocery}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Then in my .ts file I have:

```
..
 onScroll(event){
 //how do I know if the end is reached?
 }
..
```

Comment: I found this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46821717/ionic-how-to-determine-if-scroll-is-at-the-bottom-of-the-content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic - How to determine if scroll is at the bottom of the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46821717/ionic-how-to-determine-if-scroll-is-at-the-bottom-of-the-content)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the solution suggested by Wesley Coetzee, add a dummy element at the very bottom of the page and check if it is in the viewport on scorll.

Comment: I think you should upvote the answer that did help you. :D